# jquery cant get drag item id in Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having problem in getting the id of the dragged item in "sortable", can you please help me out in this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1,#div2,#div3").sortable({
        revert: true,
        accept: '.draggable',
        connectWith: [".sortable_div"],
        receive: function(e, ui) { 
            var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
            var drag_id = $(ui.item).attr('id')
            alert('alert:'+item_id+' of '+drag_id);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
</script>


<div id="div1" class="sortable_div">
<span id="span1" class="draggable"></span>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="sortable_div">
<span id="span2" class="draggable"></span>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="sortable_div">
<span id="span3" class="draggable"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

To get  draggable item id:

```
var drag_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ID by

```
receive: function(e, ui) { 
   var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
   //ui.draggable.attr('id') or ui.draggable.get(0).id or ui.draggable[0].id
   var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
   alert('alert:'+item_id+' of '+drag_id);
   console.log(ui.draggable); // to see the bunch of items
}
```

Comment: drag_id is not showing anything console is saying "undefined"

Comment: Sorry use this `alert(ui.draggable.attr('id'))`

Comment: sorry to say but its doing nothing in console it says "cant read property '0' of null"

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you want to do i think you should do something like this:

```
var drag_id = $(event.target).attr('id')
```

Comment: its similar to var item_id = $(this).attr("id"); but i need the draggable item id.

Answer (score 0):

try this dude,

```
receive: function(e, ui) { 
    var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    alert('draggable id: ' + drag_id);
}
```